# Is it possible to change or modify BIOS uuid in non virtual machine device?

Tags: windows, bios

I have a question in my mind for a long time.
I'm trying to make a software based on bios uuid.

- **Is it possible to to change a laptop or pc bios uuid?**
- **Can it be cloned or modified like hardisk uuid?**

I know this is possible in virtual machine but what about real computers?

Comment: it may change if you flash your bios with a new version, but I don't think that actually happens.

Comment: Is this a licensing thing you're working on? Please take into account that binding license to a motherboard will be a PITA for your users. Replacing a computer? Software won't work. Upgrading? Won't work. Motherboard died? Won't work.

Comment: @LPChip so it's a hard task to do not like everyone can do it via a software?

Comment: @gronostaj yes indeed , btw I believe it can't be a PITA for users because those things are very rare and I just give them new license, it's better than hard disk uuid which can be replaced with more chances than bios :p don't you think?

Comment: The way Microsoft does it may be better. They check bios uuid, harddisk uuid and other uuid's. If one of them changes, they consider it the same computer and that uuid is just updated in the database. If too many changes, they consider it a new computer and invalidate the license for manual activation

Comment: @LPChip great suggestion but my question is can a bios UUID be cloned by a user ?

Comment: In IT, everything is possible. I do think that this is going to require a very determined IT proffessional though

Comment: @LPChip I just need to prevent crackers and regular users and ofc it can be easily modified by api hooking. not evevn IT proffessional needed.